# Paint a circular image with border

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to do something like

```
new BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
        image: new DecorationImage(
          image: new ExactAssetImage('assets/images/restaurant.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(50.0)),
        border: new Border.all(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 4.0,

        ),
```

The visual I am looking for is like the way gmail shows the user's image. This code - which is from the docs - works fine, but my image should be loaded from a url, and is not in the assets.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

[`NetworkImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html) is the class you are looking for.

[image: screenshot]

```
           Container(
             width: 100.0,
             height: 100.0,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
               image: DecorationImage(
                 image: NetworkImage('http://i.imgur.com/QSev0hg.jpg'),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
               ),
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(50.0)),
               border: Border.all(
                 color: Colors.red,
                 width: 4.0,
               ),
             ),
           ),
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it puts the border on top of the image. In my case, I needed to preserve the edges of the circular image.

Comment: I recommend adding `shape: BoxShape.circle` instead of `borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(50.0)),`

Answer (score 73):

**Easy Answer**

Use two CircleAvatars together. *Examples of code & screenshot:*

```
CircleAvatar(               
 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
 radius: 60.0,
  child: CircleAvatar(
   backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/darth_vader.jpg'),
   radius: 50.0,
  ),
),
```

[image: Two CircleAvatars.]

Comment: This is very smart answer

Answer (score 35):

Flutter has already provides `CircleAvatar` widget for it.

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    radius: 50,
    backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/images/restaurant.jpg'),
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 4.0,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 9):

```
CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 28,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/avatar.jpg'),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: There's no need to write the same thing down, `CircleAvatar` has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050880/12483095)

Answer (score 8):

Use fadeInImage as recommended by flutter community to display images from network and enclosed in a container with a border decoration

```
  Widget getCircularImage(double size) {
    return Container(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(size / 2)),
        border: new Border.all(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: 4.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipOval(child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: widget.placeholderUrl,
          image: widget.imageUrl)),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

For those of you that want to create circle or a quare with rounded corners **with blur**

```
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2.0, sigmaY: 2.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 50.0,
              height: 50.0,
              child: Icon(Icons.search_rounded, color: Colors.white,),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(12.0)),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CircleAvatar without giving radius, you can use it this way.

```
CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white, //border color
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0), //border size
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: Image.asset("image.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: an explanation is often helpful

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 3):

Relative approach when a parent constraints the bound:

```
CircleAvatar(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
    child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: avatar,
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 Container(
        height: 150.0,
        width: 150.0,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              radius: 10,
              child: new Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
            )),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: new Border.all(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ));
```

Comment: There's no need to write the same thing down, `CircleAvatar` has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050880/12483095)

Answer (score 1):

For those who want the **border to be outside of the image** in other words, around the image:

```
class FramedImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImageProvider image;
  final double borderWidth;
  final Color borderColor;
  final double borderRadius;

  const FramedImage({
    required this.image,
    this.borderWidth = 2,
    this.borderColor = Colors.black,
    this.borderRadius = 2,
    Key? key
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius + borderWidth),
        border: Border.all(width: borderWidth, color: borderColor),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
        child: Image(
          image: image,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
FramedImage(
  image: NetworkImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png'),
  borderColor: Colors.blueAccent,
  // adjust this if you want a complete circle
  borderRadius: 10,
  borderWidth: 5,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
     color: Colors.white,
    ),
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: CircleAvatar(
    radius: 30,
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(ytUserImage3),
  ),
),
```

Comment: There are **11existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **one hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Padding** widget to give border to network/asset image.
Using CircleAvatar wraped with CircleAvatar is not responsive UI.

**Example:**

```
 CircleAvatar(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Image.asset(
      'images/logo.png',
      color: whiteColor,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a border inside an image:

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 42,
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    radius: 40,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 28,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: Image.asset(
        _brand.imagePath,
        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [avatar_view](https://pub.dev/packages/avatar_view) lib  which provides the functionality to show network/asset images in circular/rectangular form.

To use add below dependency

**Example:**

```
    AvatarView(
              radius: 60,
              borderWidth: 8,
              borderColor: Colors.yellow,
              avatarType: AvatarType.CIRCLE,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              imagePath:
                  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/415829/pexels-photo-415829.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-415829.jpg",
              placeHolder: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 50,),
              ),
              errorWidget: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 50,),
              ),
            ),
```

**Output:**

[image]